# xcodebuild ssh permission denied

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, permissions, xcodebuild

I generated an ssh-key and succeeded in authentication.

```
ssh -T {git address}
```

However I get `permission denied` error when cloning via **xcodebuild**.

- I just don't get it because **sometimes it works** and sometimes it doesn't.
- It **also worked** a couple of times **when I deleted** relevant credentials in the **keychain access**.
- I created a couple of repositories and tried this in several branches. Could this be a problem?

```
xcodebuild -clonedSourcePackagesDirPath .swiftpmCache
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9bdq.jpg)

Comment: "Sometimes works, sometimes doesn't" suggests (doesn't *prove*) that you have multiple ssh keys available and that your system is trying them all, and that the lock your system is poking keys into only allows a few tries. If your system tries the right key early enough, the lock opens. If not, the lock refuses to open even when you later get to the right key. To check whether this is the case, turn on debug tracing in your ssh and/or Git with `export GIT_TRACE=1; export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"` (assuming sh/bash/zsh shell).

Comment: *If* this guess turns out to be correct, *then* (and only then) using `IdentitiesOnly` in your `.ssh/config` file will by one way to fix the problem. This configuration item, which is per ssh `Host` entry, tells ssh *try only particular keys in this lock*. See the ssh configuration documentation for details.